# Reference for the rule of thumb $\sqrt{n}$ for the number of bins of an histogram

Tags: references, histogram, rule-of-thumb

Does anyone have an idea where the rule of thumb $\sqrt{n}$ for the number of bins of an histogram come from? I need a reference to put in my article. I remember that rule from my college times, but don't know who created it. Perhaps S.A. Kaufmann?

Comment: Sturges rule has a $\log(n)$ term (as does Doane's, which is based on it). Scott's rule is has bin-width proportional to $n^{-\frac13}$ (which isn't quite the same as number of bins being proportional to $n^{\frac23}$), as does the Freedman-Diaconis rule. Some people - and some programs - do use a square root rule and it seems to be pretty old; Wikipedia doesn't attribute anyone for it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Square-root_choice

Comment: Ok I will start my searches with those references :-)

Comment: Not sure that they'll help, since they're rules with different functions of n

Comment: yes I know.... but I will perhaps find some reference in their papers :-)

Comment: I wonder why you would need a reference for that. Are you working on something like an alternative rule for histograms? In that case, I'd assume "statistical folklore" might be a sufficient reference. Or are you plotting a histogram in some applied case, and a reviewer wants you to justify your choice?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: Indeed I started typing an answer immediately after writing the above, but went off looking to see if I could actually find a reference. Many hours and many rabbit-holes later, I got called away from that and only just now managed to come back to it. Unfortunately I am about to be called away again.

Comment: Yes a reviewer wants me to justify my choice. That's why I'm looking for references :-) I found some references that mention the rule, without providing its origins, but I can cite those references as well, since they present different rules for choosing bins :-)

Comment: Is it possible that a justification that didn't involve a reference might do?

Comment: I must see with the reviewer :-)